# Trying to return a list of values and words in order

Tags: python

I am trying to return a list of user inputted words and numbers in order but when I run the module, enter the words, and values it prints None instead of the terms and values in order.

```
dictionary = []

value = []

addterm1 = raw_input("Enter a term you would like to add to the dictionary: ")
addterm2 = raw_input("Enter a term you would like to add to the dictionary: ")
addterm3 = raw_input("Enter a term you would like to add to the dictionary: ")

addvalue1 = float(raw_input("Enter a number you would like to add to the set of values: "))
addvalue2 = float(raw_input("Enter a number you would like to add to the set of values: "))
addvalue3 = float(raw_input("Enter a number you would like to add to the set of values: "))

dictionary.append(addterm1)
dictionary.append(addterm2)
dictionary.append(addterm3)

value.append(addvalue1)
value.append(addvalue2)
value.append(addvalue3)

def reverseLookup(dictionary, value):

    print dictionary.sort()

    print value.sort()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reverseLookup(dictionary, value)
```

Comment: You could make this much shorter with loops, e.g. `for _ in range(3): value.append(float(raw_input(...))`. Repeating the same strings on consecutive lines is a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is an in-place method and therefore always returns `None`.  So, any calls to it should be placed on their own line.

You can make your code like this if you still want to use `list.sort`:

```
def reverseLookup(dictionary, value):
    dictionary.sort()
    value.sort()
    print dictionary
    print value
```

Or, you can use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
def reverseLookup(dictionary, value):
    print sorted(dictionary)
    print sorted(value)
```

Also, you might want to pick a different name for `dictionary` since it is a list, not a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 1):

The `.sort()` method doesn't `return` the sorted iterable, it sorts *in-place*. You need to `sort`, *then* `print`:

```
dictionary.sort()
print(dictionary)
```

Alternatively, use the `sorted()` function, which does `return` the sorted iterable:

```
print(sorted(dictionary))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different functions. [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`list.sort()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) (the one you are using now).

`sorted()` *returns* a sorted list. For example:

```
>>> a = [3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
>>> print sorted(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Which is probably what you wanted to do.

`list.sort()` *functions* the exact same way. However, it does not *return* a sorted list. Instead, it sorts the list *in-place*.

```
>>> a = [3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
>>> a.sort()
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Most in-place functions in python return `None`. So what you're trying to do is:

```
>>> a = [3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
>>> a = a.sort()
>>> print a
None
```

To fix your code, you can do `print sorted(dictionary)` and `print sorted(values)`